# Why doesn't back-slash yield non-zero exit code

Tags: bash, shell, exit-status

If run:

```
 true \ false; echo $?
```

I get an exit code of 0. Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
true \ false
```

is equivalent to

```
true ' false'
```

It causes the shell to run `true` with `false` (including an initial space character) as its parameter. The implementation of `true` that you’re using ignores this parameter and exits with a zero return value.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `true` when given any argument is unspecified by POSIX, some implementations may very well return a syntax error and a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Backticks won't preserve the leading space. You'll have to use `<code> false</code>` for that.

Comment: @muru `<code>` doesn’t either, at least not for me...

Comment: @StephenKitt hmmm, works for me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329041/270345 Ah, well.

Comment: @muru weird, I get https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329043/285232

Answer (score 4):

You're just running the command `true` with some arguments. Since those arguments aren't options, it doesn't matter what they are.